# Batch update URLs inside documents (PDF, DOC, XLS) within SharePoint Document Library

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-enterprise, document-library, url

Our IT department is in the process of moving over the 2010 farm to 2013. There will be some lag-behind sites that wish to retain the original URL because the impact is too great to fix right now moving to a 2013 deployment.

I was contemplating moving our site over but we would be forced to have a new URL. The problem is that we have a number of hard-coded links within documents in a couple document libraries. There are Excel, PDF, Visio, etc files in the document library. Is there any possible way to automate or semi-automate the replacement of those URLs without having to manually scrub every single file individually?

Comment: It's a bit late, but I think I found a solution for word and excel documents https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/q/280707/18129